# Power BI Embedding

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I'm using Power BI REST API's to integrate or embed the reports created in Power BI. By using these API's i'm getting Access token, Embed token, Report Id, Data-set Id and Embed URL also but when i embed my report using J query Ajax then it gives me the pref-light error. So, please let me know how to solve this error. In addition of this i have Power BI Pro account. Below are the API's and screenshot of error.

1. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
2. https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/976sdsdf-c82e-4217-9f74-3c50e694fe6f/reports
3. https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/9765dc8f-c82e-4217-9f74-3c50e6qwwq6f/reports/32fwdqwa-e31b-4676-b598-7268baa5be75/GenerateToken

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if relevant
[Got 400 error for pre-flight options CORS token request from OWIN-based WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826706/got-400-error-for-pre-flight-options-cors-token-request-from-owin-based-webapi)

Also, can you maybe check what is the response itself that is returned? what is there besides the 400? maybe some message?